# Tomcat 8 war deploy LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm having a Spring Boot application that I package by clicking on package in intellij. I take the generated war file and upload it on my tomcat8. When I click on deploy I get this exception:

```
30-Nov-2018 14:57:53.611 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
30-Nov-2018 14:57:53.611 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
30-Nov-2018 14:57:53.622 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
30-Nov-2018 14:57:56.558 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/Foo'
30-Nov-2018 14:58:01.229 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log FAIL - Application at context path [/Foo] could not be started
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Foo]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - Failed to create parent directories for [/./logs/spring-boot-logger.log]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - openFile(./logs/spring-boot-logger.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/spring-boot-logger.log (No such file or directory)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:290)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 35 more

30-Nov-2018 14:58:01.229 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

When my friend checks out the git repo and does the same we don't have any problems the deploy succeed.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

Logback file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="PAPERTRAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>logs7.papertrailapp.com</syslogHost>
        <port>1337</port>
        <facility>USER</facility>
        <suffixPattern>FOO: %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>

    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="PAPERTRAIL" />
    </root>

    <!-- LOG at TRACE level -->
    <logger name="foo" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="PAPERTRAIL" />
    </logger>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: seems like error in logback configuration file

Comment: so please post logback.xml file. it would help to point the issue

Comment: I have updated the post with the logback file

Comment: inside your project create logs/spring-boot-logger.log and try

Comment: I did that and that error is gone but still the lyfecycleexception. I dont get it.

Comment: getting same error or new kind of error?

Comment: The same except that the logfile part is gone.

Comment: Can you please update error section again with new error?

Answer (score 0):

looks like required jar is missing or jar file is missing when download.

find org.springframework.boot in the maven depository and delete this jar.

maven install;

maven will download again;

deploy again;

Comment: Where do I need to find the org.springframework.boot?

Comment: C:\Users\youname\.m2\repository

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
    ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - Failed to create parent directories for [/./logs/spring-boot-logger.log]
    ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - openFile(./logs/spring-boot-logger.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/spring-boot-logger.log (No such file or directory)
```

so create in your project directory

```
logs/spring-boot-logger.log file
```